# Same query producing different results

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Below is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(CID INT,PID INT,STAT VARCHAR(20),TIN DATETIME, TOUT DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #TEMP(CID,STAT,PID,TIN,TOUT)
    SELECT DISTINCT CID,STST,PID,TIN,TOUT 
    FROM CVTBL
    WHERE STAT = 'YES' 
    AND PID = '12' 
    ORDER BY CID DESC;

select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```

This is a very straight forward query. However everytime when I run the select * from #temp it produced different result sets but the total number of rows is the same. How does that work?

Comment: Produces different results from what?  I see only one query.  I would point out that underlying data can change, and so the same query can generate different results.

Comment: Edited the query

Comment: All tables are considered to be unordered sets, so until you specify an `order by` clause on the `select * from #temp` the same records can show up in any order.

Comment: It doesn't produce different results ... if you would have specific order by `select * from #temp order by CID desc` you would see it's the same

Comment: So, do you have `Select * from #TEMP` and then `Select * from CVTBL`? And the two queries result in different data sets? If so, add that to your question.

Comment: @Larry no I want to query #temp table alone

Comment: Both Veljko89 and tarheel have given you the answer here, @Jiah.

Comment: I compared the result set and the records match up but they get ordered differently everytim e when I run the query.

Comment: If the reaultset only differ in Order then note that its not guaranteed that inserting in temp table will keep same order as the query that inserts it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to elaborate on this as an answer,but both Veljko89 and tarheel have hit the nail on the head in the comments they made on the OP's question.

Data, in SQL Server, is stored in **unordered** HEAPS. Regardless of the order you `INSERT` the data, regardless of if you have a `CLUSTERED INDEX` or not, performing a `SELECT` statement without an `ORDER BY` has no guarenteed order. Period.

The only (yes that's right **ONLY**) way to guarentee the order of a result set is to (unsurprisingly) use the `ORDER BY` clause. If you omit that clause SQL Server will return the rows in whatever order it processed that rows, which could be any order at all. For small tables, yes, you are likely to get the same order, and if you have a `CLUSTERED INDEX` then that improves that possibility, but that's just it, it's a possibility.

Once you get to larger tables, and start introducing multiple cores processing the information, then the order will become more and more randomised; as with larger datasets the data that is read first is more likely to vary, and with multiple cores one may finish processing its data first, however, had data from "further" in the table.

So, in summary: **Add an `ORDER BY` clause (so that each column has a unique set) to ensure your queries *always* return data in the same order.**

Comment: Inside the ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY .... ORDER BY .....) also make sure orderby clause in right order to make sure output data is consistent

Comment: not sure on your point, @RamkumarSambandam , however you can't use `ROW_NUMBER` without an `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause. So you would have to define the order when using the function, and thus the ordering will have some consistency.

Comment: if there are 10 column in the table and only 3 column is used in order by along with partition to select the unique row for the combination (3 column) remaining 7 column data get changed for every execution  as they are not in order by clause.

Comment: My SQL Query has an order by and still produces different results, so this answer is not correct.

Comment: @Black then your `ORDER BY` doesn't create a unique order-able value for every row. it is certainly not wrong, I can assure you of that. If you do think it's wrong, post a question, citing this question (and explaining why it isn't a dupliiate) and I'll be happy to try to prove otherwise. :) Especially as you've downvoted this answer.

Comment: Please do ping me (here) the question URL when you've posted it, @Black , so that I can give it attention. Thanks.

Comment: @Larnu, I had to change my order by from `order by category ASC` to `order by category ASC, title`

Comment: Exactly as i suspected, @Black , and why I said that this answer isn't wrong. I would appreciate if you removed the downvote, :)

Comment: @Larnu, yes, but your answer does not explain the problem in full detail. You said that just adding Order By will solve the problem, but you did not told us that we might need to add multiple orders. I try to edit your question to explain it, so I can remove the downvote.

Comment: I haven't asked a question here, @Black , only provided an answer. But, like I said, my answer isn't wrong; adding an `ORDER BY` *does* cause your results to be consistent. You have proved that. The problem you had was that your `ORDER BY` didn't create a unique value to order by.

Comment: @Larnu, yes and I had problems solving my problem since you did not made that clear in your post.